# How to handle an upvoted answer that doesn't attempt to answer my question?

Tags: discussion

I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210788/how-can-i-enable-html-entity-highlighting-in-vs-code) that I have placed a bounty on to attract more attention as it had not received any answers.  Today, it received an answer that is not related to my question.  The answerer (not posting the name here, because I'm not trying to shame this user) didn't read my question and answered as if I were using a different piece of software (although my question is tagged properly, describes it clearly in the question itself and has screenshots.)  It's not Not An Answer, because it *is* an answer (not a comment or question), but just not an answer to *my* question.  I know I could just comment that it was unhelpful and downvote, but it's collecting more upvotes than downvotes and I fear that others will consider my question "answered" and it will lessen the odds of me getting an actual answer to my question.  Not to mention the fact that my bounty will be automatically assigned to this answer, which I feel is not fair.

I want to know how should I handle this.

Comment: Your bounty will only be automatically assigned when the answer has more then 2 total score and is the top scored answer.

Comment: @Magisch Although that's not currently the case, I fear it'll get another upvote and that could happen.

Comment: Bounties get you attention, they are no guarantee of correct or appropriate answers.  You paid for the advert, you have to live with the result.

Comment: @Floern I didn't see that question after a quick search, so thank you for pointing that one. The answers there are disappointing, but helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do the same thing you'd do for any other incorrect answer that you come across.  Downvote the answer.  If you also want to comment on the answer to explain why it's wrong, you're free to do so.

The only other thing you could really consider is that, when people post answers that clearly misunderstand the question it is a sign that the question might not be as clear as you think it is.  You could consider looking over the question to see why they might have misunderstood it, and clarify it better.  But if other readers of the question seem to understand it, and this seems like an isolated case, and you don't see any way of making the question more clear, then you've done what you can.